# Relational database on a slow storage

Tags: database, storage

I'm trying to pick a RDBMS for usage as a backend for KDE's Akonadi PIM framework.

Problem is that the storage (/home partition) resides on a pretty slow SD card with *reiser4* filesystem on it. The filesystem is based on COW and transactional model itself, so its `fsync()` performance is very low - while InnoDB uses it for its own transaction system. Hence the whole system is practically unusable.

What can be done to improve this? Possible backends for Akonadi are: **MySQL** (with *InnoDB* and *MyISAM* backends), **PostgreSQL** and **SQLite**. Actually, no scalability is needed as there is the only client.

Comment: use a faster SD card?

Comment: For something like this I would say MySQL and PostgreSQL are overkill - SQLite is much more, well, light and doesn't involve a server.

Comment: Hm. I've just tested SQLite against both MySQL backends and it seems that SQLite is not any faster than MySQL/InnoDB. And by the way, MySQL/MyISAM is actually a whole lot faster (no benchmarks, just user experience) than both of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...So I've done some research.

I've tested:

1. **MySQL** with *InnoDB* backend - nearly unusable
2. **SQLite** - also pretty unusable, speed drastically decreases with total row count
3. **PostgreSQL** - not tested, because the corresponding Qt's database driver was not available
4. **MySQL** with *MyISAM* backend - no lockups altogether; perfectly suits me.

Yes, I know that *MyISAM* is not transactional and hence I'm risking integrity of data... But for Akonadi (which is just a caching frontend) it is completely ok.